# Prove sum of square of sides equal to sum of square of diagonals plus 4 times...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

See photo below for complete problem description. I approached the problem using cosine law on the intersection; setting up equations. I do know that the segments are half the diagonals. I can't obtain the final form base on the figure I made. How should I approach this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The last sentence of the problem is incomplete. And the equation you labelled "Prove" cannot be right, because it's dimensionally flawed.

Comment: In fact, your theorem as stated is wrong. You can see the right one here: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/horizons/Quad%20Speaking.pdf as Theorem 3.

Comment: May i ask where did you find this fake theorem? Or is it a creation of yours?

Comment: @Aretino I got this question from a book. From gelfands trigonometria. I screenedshot the image. I tried to prove this one for 2 hours and was unsuccesful hence asked for help...

Comment: The figure is personally drawn.

Comment: I just noticed that they are dimensionally inconsistent. Thanks for pointing that one out.

Comment: You are right, I checked Gelfand's book: it may be a translation error, with "length" erroneously replacing "square".